# PHP: Making my code simpler/shorter welcome message

Tags: php

Any suggestion to make this welcome message shorter:

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  if(isSet($_SESSION['1stTime'])){
  ?>
  <strong id="welcome" style="font-size: 10px;">
  <a href="logout.php">
  Logga ut
  </a>
  </strong>
  <?php
  }else{
  $_SESSION['1stTime'] = time();
  ?>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#welcome").fadeIn("slow");
   setTimeout(function(){
   $("#welcome").fadeOut("slow"); 
    setTimeout(function(){
     $("#welcome").html("<a href='logout.php'>Logga ut</a>");
     $("#welcome").fadeIn();
     }, 800);
   }, 5000);
  });
  </script>
  <strong id="welcome" style="display: none; color: #FFF; font-size: 10px;">Hej, <?php echo $FULL; ?>!</strong>
  <?php 
  } 
  }
  ?>
```

First it checks if you are signed in. Next if 1stTime is set, if it is then show "Log out" in swedish, if it isnt, then introduce with "Hi, NAME", and then change to "Log out" after 5 seconds(jquery) + set the session

How can i make this simpler?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your jQuery code to this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#welcome").fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow").delay(800).html("<a href='logout.php'>Logga ut</a>").fadeIn();
    });
```

But as for the rest of your code, I can not see any way to make it smaller or simpler

Answer (score 0):

I'd find it simpler to separate your javascript, php, and static HTML instead of having them all intertwined.  Almost all of the "work" here is javascript, all we need from PHP is a few seesion variables and possibly setting one.

I'm going to use hidden inputs bc I don't care for small little php tags, nad i think it helps to demonstrate what the roles of PHP and JS are in this situation.  I made `logout` and `intro` into different elements, but thats not too important you can make them one in the same again if you prefer.

```
<strong id="logout" style="font-size: 10px;">   
   <a href="logout.php">   Logga ut   </a>   
</strong> 

<strong id="intro" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 10px;">

</strong>

<?php
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='hasUserId' value='" . isset($_SESSION['user_id'] . "' />";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='hasPriorLogin' value='" . isset($_SESSION['1stTime'] . "' />";

   echo "<input type='hidden' id='fullName' value='" . isset($FULL) ? $FULL : 'noname' . "' />";

    if (!isset($_SESSION['1stTime']) $_SESSION['1stTime'] = time();
?>

<script>         
    $(document).ready(function() {   

       $("#intro").hide(); $("#logout").hide();  //start with both strong blocks hidden

       if ($("#hasUserId").val()) //everything is dependent on being logged in
       {
           if ($("#hasPriorLogin").val())    //not the users first time
           {
               $("#logout").fadeIn("slow"); 
           }
           else                            //the users first time
           {
                $("#intro").html("Hey" + $("#fullName").val() + "!");
                $("#intro").show();
                $("#intro").fadeOut("slow").delay(5000);
                $("#logout").fadeIn("slow").delay(5800);
           }
       }
   });      
</script>
```

I'm not sure If i got your fadeIn/fadeOut exactly the same but you see where to change it.  I'm hoping the separation here makes the code more clear, if not necessarily shorter.  All the session information is available right off the bat, so the only control flow you need to worry about is in the javascript.